# Get WebRtc AudioTrack from pointer

Tags: java, android, webrtc, webrtc-android

Is there any way that I can do to get audioTrack from this pointer ?

I want to get real stream with ByteBuffer or something similar without forking webrtc

```
package org.webrtc;
public class AudioTrack extends MediaStreamTrack {
  /** Returns a pointer to webrtc::AudioTrackInterface. */
  long getNativeAudioTrack() {
    return getNativeMediaStreamTrack();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(Stream_object.audioTracks.size() > 0){
    Stream_object.audioTracks.get(0);
    audioTrack.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: This will play it audomatillay, I want to get byte buffer from it.
Can I somehow obtain it?

Comment: yeah, it going to play with the default output of audio, I've get audio like this but, about the byte buffer thing Idk.

Comment: On webrtc there is very less reference so trying my best to get what you need from my current work experience with webrtc

Comment: @sourabhkarmakar you find a solution to get remote audio bytebuffer.

Comment: no I haven't work on it after that so I don't know @bhardwaj

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for audio byte buffers that are captured by webrtc from the microphone, then implement `SamplesReadyCallback` callback in `JavaAudioDeviceModule`.
`AudioSamples` has the byte buffer data that is captured by webrtc

```
public static interface SamplesReadyCallback {
    void onWebRtcAudioRecordSamplesReady(AudioSamples samples);
  }
```